# vba - attaching a file based on cell value and if there is no cell value then no file should be attached

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this forum and also new to programming.
I am trying to create a If condition in VBA where if the excel file has the required value then the file should get attached with a specific email or else no file should be attached ( in case the cell value is blank) and a different email should appear in the Email body.

I am trying to use "NULL" to represent the blank cell value. Is it correct?

Sample of my code -

if sheets("Hello").range("A2").value = Null, then 
.attachments.remove
else 
.attachments.add "C:\filename.xlsx
End if

Comment: No, you should use either `If Worksheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value = "" Then` or, more appropriately, `If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value) Then`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. :) I used If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value) Then and it worked perfectly. Sorry not sure how to vote in the comments provide by you.. so wrote a new comment thanking for your help.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Sheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value = Null Then
```

is **not** the correct way to check for an empty cell.

One of the ways to test for an empty cell would be:

```
If Worksheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value = "" Then
```

which tests whether the cell, when converted to a String, is an empty string.  (An equivalent statement to that would be

```
If Worksheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value = vbNullString Then
```

which can save you a few bytes of memory.)

A better way to test would be to use the actual `IsEmpty` function:

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Hello").Range("A2").Value) Then
```

which tests to see whether the cell's value has a data type of `Variant/Empty`.